# Use the same JavaScript code for different divs

Tags: javascript, css, html

This is my JavaScript code:

### Javascript

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#showButton").click(function(){ $("#showContent").toggle("slow");  
}); }); </script>
```

The question is how I can use same code for different `<div>`

Like using this code to open `<div id=#showContent></div>` and using same code but separately open `<div id=#showContentSecond></div>`

I have a lot of `div` elements and I don't want to code something everytime I want to manipulate an element.

Comment: I removed Java tag since java!=javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button will need to be related to the div in some way, if it isn't a child of the div, example:

```
<button class="mybutton" data-something="1">One</button>
<button class="mybutton" data-something="2">Two</button>

<div data-something="1">first</div>
<div data-something="2">second</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.mybutton').click(function(){
        $('div[data-something=' + $(this).data('something') + ']').toggle();
    });
});
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vcAtb/

Comment: @DenisS no problem :) if this solved your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick

Answer (score 0):

You can use the document.getElementsByTagName element to get all divs.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

Answer (score -2):

Apply a CSS `class` to each element you want to have the same behavior

### HTML

```
<div id="div1" class="toggleDiv"></div>
<div id="div2" class="toggleDiv"></div>
<div id="div3" class="toggleDiv"></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".toggleDiv").click(function()
    { 
        $(this).toggle("slow");  
    });
 });
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/gDG6n/**

Comment: Probably because the buttons are the clickable elements, and not the divs.